# How can I parse invalid JSON to Java Object using Pojo Class

Tags: java, json, pojo

I'm not sure what format this object is in but can I parse the following invalid JSON object to Java class Pojo? I tried doing it using Jackson but since it's invalid, I was wondering if pojo class would work?

```
{ 
    name: (sindey, crosby)
    game: "Hockey"
    type: athlete
}
```

The file would have multiple objects of this format

Answer (score 0):

Geesh, don't recognise this format! If you want to use Jackson you could pre-process you data to wrap the values... perhaps a regex to catpure the groups and wrap the values in quotes something like `(name|type):\s(.+)` => `$1: "$2"`

> I was wondering if pojo class would work?

Sure, you could make that work with a simple parser; plenty of room for improvement, but something like this would do it:

```
    Record record = null;
    var records = new LinkedList<>();
    // I'm using a reader as example, but just provide lines any way you like
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.trim();
        // may need to skip empty lines if you have them in your file...
        if (line.equals("{")) {
            record = new Record();
            records.add(record);
        } else {
            // may need substrings if your data contains ":"
            var tokens = line.split(":");
            var field = tokens[0];
            var value = tokens[1];
            if (field.equals("name")) {
                // perhaps shuffle the format to something nicer here..
                record.setName(value);
            }
            /// same for game and type fields...
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could add a limit parameter to the split method to only split after the key, but I'd recommend using a HashMap rather than some Record object since the setter methods might not all be known ahead of time